# How do I control text output with xslt stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

Xml file `test.xml`,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sect1>
  <title>Some title</title>
  <para>sect 1 begin</para>

  <variablelist>
    <varlistentry>
      <term>term 1</term>
      <listitem>
        <para>para 1-1</para>
        <para>para 1-2</para>
      </listitem>
    </varlistentry>

    <varlistentry>
      <term>term 2</term>
      <listitem>
        <para>para 2-1</para>
        <para>para 2-2</para>
      </listitem>
    </varlistentry>

  </variablelist>
  <para>sect 1 end</para>
</sect1>
```

Stylesheet file `test.xslt`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="sect1/variablelist">
        <xsl:for-each select="varlistentry">
            <xsl:value-of select="term"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to process with `xsltproc`,

```sh
xsltproc test.xslt test.xml
```

Which produces output,

```
  Some title
  sect 1 begin

  term 1term 2
  sect 1 end
```

I was expecting to see,

```
term 1
term 2
```

The questions I have,

- Why do I see "Some title sect 1 begin.." etc. I did not not select them.
- Why do I see extra indent and whitespaces.
- How do I put line break between "term 1" and "term 2".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is all due to what is called the "XSLT processing model". Read a good book about XSLT (one of Michael Kay's books) or watch a course on XSLT like: https://www.pluralsight.com/player?course=xslt-foundations-part1&author=dimitre-novatchev&name=xslt-foundations-part1-m4&clip=0&mode=live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing starts at the document node, the root node, using your templates if you write them or the built-in ones https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule if you haven't provided any matching template.

As for unwanted whitespace, use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`.

As for the other elements, you have at least two options:

1. Match the root node and apply-templates to the elements or nodes you want to process: `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="sect1/variablelist"/></xsl:template>`
2. Change the built-in rule on text nodes to not output them: `<xsl:template match="text()"/>`

Of course the whole mixture of templates and for-each seems odd, I would use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="sect1/variablelist/varlistentry/term"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 2 or 3 it boils down to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="sect1/variablelist/varlistentry/term" separator="&#10;"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It's generally a better idea to use newline as a line *terminator* rather than a line *separator*. Otherwise concatenating it with something else fails badly.

Comment: @o11c, if that is your opinion, fine, I tried to answer the question 'How do I put line break between "term 1" and "term 2"'.